# disconnect client from socket.io id

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I can connect specific player to specific room like:

```
socket.join('sampleroom');
```

And documentation says that 'you can use leave method to leave room' like:

```
socket.leave('sampleroom');
```

But I just want any client to leave using io object instead of socket. I need something like:

```
io.sockets(specificSocketID).leave('sampleroom');
```

Is there any way to leave client from room using just socket id with io object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tresdin mentioned, we can store socket ids, however io object is also stored so actually we don't need it. We can use specific socket id like

```
io.sockets.sockets[specificSocketID].leave('sampleroom');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the incoming sockets into your own object.

```
var sockets = {};
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    sockets[specificSocketID] = socket;
    io.on('disconnect',function(){
        delete sockets[specificSocketID];
    });
});
//then you can easily call a specific socket with its id
sockets[specificSocketID].join('sampleRoom');
sockets[specificSocketID].leave('sampleRoom');
```

Answer (score 0):

For version > 3.0

```
io.sockets.sockets.get(specificSocketID).leave("sampleroom");
```

For version  < 3.0

```
io.sockets.sockets[specificSocketID].leave("sampleroom");
```